# What does it mean to run a local web server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, webserver

I can program and develop in Ruby on Rails/JS/HTML/CSS to make a full stack app. However, there are holes in my understanding of the HTTP request/response cycle. Are the following points correct?

- If I make a Rails app, and on the command line type `rails server` I get a local server, which I can make requests to. If I open a browser, type `localhost:3000`, and press enter, I am making an HTTP request to the local server.
- Rails uses by default a web server called WEBrick, though there are others like Thin, Puma, and Unicorn. These are all pieces of software, and what makes them web servers is the fact that the software implements functionality to process HTTP requests.
- When I run a local web server, it means that my computer is running one of these pieces of software that listen for HTTP requests.

**Is the above what it means "to run a local web server"?**

- I have seen other examples of ways to "run a local web server". One of the is to run `npm install -g http-server` in a project directory, and then navigate to `localhost:8080`. Is this also just software that starts running and accepts HTTP requests on port 8080?
- On a Ruby command line, install rack gem: `gem install rack`. Then in a new Ruby file we `require 'rack'`, start a web server:

`Rack::Server.start({ app: MySimpleApp, port: 3000 })`

We can then define a web application `MySimpleApp` that is rack-compliant (object that responds to `call` method):

```
class MySimpleApp
  def self.call
    (...)
  end
end
```

So now when we navigate in our browser to localhost:3000, MySimpleApp is executed. **Is rack simply running it's default WEBrick server? Is what the above commands do simply run a local web server and define what to do when an HTTP request comes in (execute MySimpleApp)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty much right on your understanding there. HTTP is just a text-based protocol that, like many, operates over TCP/IP.

The built-in WEBrick server isn't the best example of an HTTP server written in Ruby, but it's included for legacy reasons because it's often "good enough" to get you started. [Pow](http://pow.cx) is considerably better and despite being produced by the same company that produced Rails it's largely written in Node.

The beauty of HTTP, like a lot of internet based protocols, is it doesn't matter what language you use so long as you comply with the standard.

Rack is a layer that operates behind HTTP and provides a thin layer of abstraction on the request/response cycle.

Comment: Careful with the first paragraph: HTTP may *look* like it were text-based. But it really is a binary protocol: it operates on octets, not characters.

Comment: @DaSourcerer I'm not sure that's a distinction that's important for a protocol based on 7-bit ASCII or extensions to [encode other formats](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987). Bytes and characters are the same here unless otherwise specified. The framing is plain-text. The payloads *may* be binary.

Comment: Not going to start a fight over this, but yes, while bearly visible in practice, it is important. Codewords and delimiters fitting into 7bit ASCII is actually a way to prevent interoperability issues and allow the protocol to be read bytewise. Oh, and some headers introduced before RFC 5987 allow raw UTF8 payloads. `Cookie2` being one of them, I think.

Comment: The line does get blurred when using some extensions, but at its core it's a CRLF text-based protocol that can be, if necessary, emulated by typing things in over `telnet`. That's not possible with a binary protocol. I understand what you're saying, but it's an academic distinction.

Comment: "it's an academic distinction." In light of the rather subtle effects in practice, I think I can settle with that :)

Answer (score 3):

A server is something that opens up a port (80, 443, 8080) for some sort of data transfer. Port 80 is the HTTP port and port 443 is the HTTPS port. 8080 is a commonly used port for development (as is 3000). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

A local server by definition is a server running on your machine.

Overall, you are definitely on the right track.